# Reading last whole word from variable

Tags: string, variables, tcl, eggdrop

I am currently making a script that manipulates several files, and I am trying to read the last whole word from a variable (`$pio`).

The string is variable in length and word count and is set to `$pio` in the start of the function.

I have tried to read the last word in the line/variable separated by a whitespace with "strip" but this far I have only been able to read by character count.

Is it possible to read the whole last word of the string and parse it into a new variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the string and then take the last index:

```
set lastWord [lindex [split $pio] end]
```

Or if you don't mind using a little regexp, you can use something like this:

```
regexp -- {\S+$} $pio lastWord
```

`\S+` is an expression to match at least 1 non-space character, and `$` makes sure that this match occurs at the end of the string. The match will be stored a variable named `lastWord`.

[codepad demo](http://codepad.org/iuhqOSoi)

Comment: Probably a good idea to `string trim` before the `split` or `regexp`.

Comment: Didn't consider that, but that's true. With user input, we can never be too sure!